# modal not closing on clicking anchor tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have designed a bootstrap modal in my application. Modal shows a signup form. When user clicks the login which is an anchor tag i want to close the modal so that i can show login modal. Jquery not getting the id of anchor tag. How to do it.
Here's my modal code:

```
  <div class="modal fade modal-white" id="signup" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Signup</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


      <form id="signupForm" method="post" action="/signup">
        <h1>create an account</h1>
        <input name="user[name]" type="text" placeholder="What's your username?" pattern="^[\w]{3,16}$" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" class="input pass"/>
        <input name="user[password]" type="password" placeholder="Choose a password" required="required" class="input pass"/>
        <input name="user[password2]" type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" required="required" class="input pass"/>
        <input name="user[email]" type="email" placeholder="Email address" class="input pass"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign me up!" class="inputButton"/>
        <div class="text-center">
            already have an account? <a href="#" id="login_id">login</a>
        </div>
      </form>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Now heres my jquery code as i try to get #login_id clicked and close the current modal.

```
 $("#signupForm #login_id").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#signup').modal('toggle'); 
});
```

Comment: Looks fine [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRRymV](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRRymV)

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar We don't know when OP tried to register this even listener. Probably there is no DOM available or who knows.

Comment: You're right my friend. I commented, not answered :) He can guide community and give more information by that. Anyway you're probably right about the no DOM available.. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you don't have DOM ready when you are trying to bind click event. In this case wrap your code into `$(function() { ... })`. Or make sure your script is located after HTML.

But you don't even need javascript if you just want to close modal. Simply add `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute to your login link and Bootstrap will bind necessary actions to it for you:

```
<div class="text-center">
  already have an account? <a href="#" id="login_id" data-dismiss="modal">login</a>
</div>
```

Comment: i know the data dismiss property. I want to close signup modal and open a new modal. So for that i need jquery. I have used $ function .

Comment: I understand what you want. I'm saying: don't use your own click event to close the first modal. Use `data-dismiss="modal"` because Bootstrap already listens for events coming from `data-dismiss="modal"` elements and closes modals for you. So no need to bind one more. You want to open new modal? Then you should subscribe to `hidden.bs.modal` event of the first modal and open second one from this event handler. `$('#signup').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() { /* open new modal */ })`

Comment: $('#signup').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() { 
        $('#login').modal('show');
      });       Is this fine.... it still doesnot work. How to check if dom is available to jquery .

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ $('#signup').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() { 
        $('#login').modal('show');
      });

});
</script>

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Should work: http://plnkr.co/edit/uaJDmu3eWbnQxmKMEGWQ?p=preview

Comment: Works in chrome but in Safari, it doesn't close the dialog and behaves like a normal anchor tag.